# How can I join on null?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my table structure:

```
-- qanda (stands for questions and answers)
+----+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
| id |  title  |                      content                  |  question_id |
+----+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
| 1  | title1  | this is a question                            | NULL         |
| 2  | NULL    | this is an answer                             | 1            |
| 3  | NULL    | this is another answer                        | 1            |
| 4  | title2  | this is another question                      | NULL         |
| 5  | NULL    | this is an answer for the second question     | 4            |
| 6  | NULL    | this is another answer for the first question | 1            |
+----+---------+-----------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

I know, it would be much better if I keep the questions and answers in two different tables. But now I'm just trying to understand how exactly `JOIN` works in this case.

---

I have an id of `qanda` table and I always want a title. That id might be either the id of a question or the id of an answer. How can I do that?

---

I want something like this:

```
SELECT t1.title
FROM qanda t1
INNER JOIN qanda t2
ON t1.id = t2.question_id
WHERE t1.id = :id
```

My query matches nothing. And here are some samples of the expected results:

```
-- :id = 1
+--------+
| title1 |
+--------+

-- :id = 2
+--------+
| title1 |
+--------+

-- :id = 4
+--------+
| title2 |
+--------+

-- :id = 5
+--------+
| title2 |
+--------+

-- :id = 6
+--------+
| title1 |
+--------+
```

Comment: post script of your create tables

Comment: @etsa May I ask what do you need that for? The table structure is pretty much clear in my question.

Comment: it's clear for you... not for me... if you need help, post what requested

Comment: @etsa Yes obviously I want your help. But honestly I don't have any script. What's in my question is a simplified of my real table structure which has lots of other columns.

Comment: To give support  I need create table and expected output.  You can create tables as you have in your mind , verify them, verify your query and then and only then ask for help.  If you post what requested I will be happy (and with me many other SO members) to try to help you

Comment: @etsa Lemme ask this way: [Here is my table structure](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb083c/13), and it works as expected when the entry id is the id of an **answer**. Now I want to make it working also when the entry id is id of a **question**.

Comment: @etsa I agree with the OP here. Table structure is irrelevant.  The illustration of the table provided is entirely sufficient to answer the question.

Comment: Use a left join.  `SELECT coalesce(t2.title, t1.title)
FROM qanda t1
LEFT JOIN qanda t2
  ON t1.id = t2.question_id
WHERE (t1.id = :id or T2.ID = :id)`

Comment: @xQbert It is not that mush simple you think.

Comment: Did you try it? (I think it is)

Comment: @xQbert Yes, yours returns two rows http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb083c/33

Comment: `where t1.title is not null`  it assumes that all answers will have a null title and all questions will have a title and that answers tie to questions only and questions will not tie to questions.

Comment: http://rextester.com/GHU72472 updated needed a distinct

Comment: @xQbert Nice, thank you. Just do you think your solution is better or the second solution *(the alternative one)* of @Serg?

Comment: I think it would result in the same execution plan or very similar.  The only variance would be w/ a left join if you have questions w/o answers his would return nothing whereas mine would return the question.

Comment: @xQbert I see, please write your solution as an answer under my question.

Comment: That's one ugly design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Serg; but using a left join will allow questions with out (w/o) answers to appear in the results if you have such a situation.

```
SELECT distinct coalesce(t2.title, t1.title) as title
FROM qanda t1 
LEFT JOIN qanda t2 
  ON t1.id = t2.question_id 
WHERE (t1.id = 1 or T2.ID = 1)
  and Type = 0;
```

If we can assume a title only exists on questions and no answers will have titles.

I think this is harder to maintain, it should be faster as it eliminates the join (kinda the exists can early escape where the join wouldn't be able to and since the limit occurs on the subquery we only have 1 record really to deal with on the join) and the distinct.

```
SELECT t1.title as title
FROM qanda t1 
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM qanda t2 
               WHERE ID = 1 
                 and t1.ID = t2.question_id)  --correlated subquery
           or t1.id = 1)
  and Type = 0
```

Comment: does "w/o" means "without"?

Comment: Also that `distinct` is redundant, since `id` is PK, right?

Comment: the distinct is required.  Since a question could have multiple answers the multiple rows would appear in result due to the join.  As the op is after just 1 title; regardless of how many answers a question has.  in all honesty I don't think the coalese is needed if I handled the join better...

Comment: Yeah once I made the assumption that no answer would have a title, then the need for the join disappeared as only questions would have titles and from that we just needed to get the title for a specific ID which was 1 level deep.

Comment: As a noted, I think it would be better *(I don't know how)* we check if entry id is the id of an answer the do the join, otherwise no need to join.

Comment: Eliminating the or would be beneficial; but I can't see how we can do it; and the exists is darn fast if ID is indexed

Comment: Yes I know you last query is fast enough. I just want to say in reality I've one column named `type` which is `0` for questions and `1` fo answers. Isn't that useful here?

Comment: on second thought no... since ID is the PK and we have an index on it and we're only looking for 1 ID at a time.  I don't see how.  the UNIQUEness of the ID is sufficient; but I could be missing something.

Comment: Ah ok. btw you second query returns null for answers http://rextester.com/BWWKG44938

Comment: and now that Type would come in handy :P  Since the main query we only want to be questions... better to use type than check for is not null or

Comment: had a bug too `and t1.ID = t2.id) ` should have been `and t1.ID = t2.question_id)`http://rextester.com/WYTJP58269 and to show all permutations: http://rextester.com/MEOU1923

Comment: Great .. yes it works totally as expected. Just which one is your choose? I mean do you recommend I go with which approach in your answer? Also what indexes do I need exactly?

Comment: I like the 2nd for performance the 1st for maintainability. Just depends on what's more important to you.  a combined index on ID and type in that order would/should give you the biggest benefit.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your responses. This is my last question: Isn't there any different in the order of conditions? I mean isn't this better? `. . . t1.id = 1 or EXSITS ( . . . ) . . .`

Comment: Generally not.  Most modern compilers re-arrange the SQL to best suit the cost based optimizer (CBO) based on table statistics.  You could always try both and look at the execution plans of both; but I suspect they will yield the same performance/plan.  So then it just becomes what's easier to maintain/read.  I say generally because the CBO can pick some strange things sometimes; and more complex queries re-arranging can matter.

Answer (score 3):

Union  of 2 queries

```
SELECT t1.title
FROM qanda t1
WHERE t1.id = :id and t1.title IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT t1.Title
FROM qanda t2
JOIN qanda t1
ON t1.id = t2.question_id
WHERE t2.id = :id
```

Alternatively

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.title
FROM qanda t1
JOIN qanda t2
ON t1.id = t2.question_id
WHERE :id in ( t2.id, t1.id)
```

Comment: Yes this is the only working answer, by seems a heavy query. thanks anyway. upvote

Comment: Great .. I like your alternative approach. Just do you think which one is better? Your first approach or the second one?

Comment: The second should run faster, just a guess.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Also, do you know which columns make a benefit o index?

Comment: Id and question_Id  are obvious candidates.

Comment: Alright .. and my last question, can you please tell me what's the reason of using `DISTINCT`?

Comment: You may wish to get rid of `DISTINCT` as well provided `id` is a PK (most probably but not stated explicitly).

Comment: A `UNION ALL` might be faster in the first one. This has the same effect as removing the `DISTINCT` in the second one.  Just a note also that the second approach will exclude questions that have no answer.  I'm not sure that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT title 
FROM qanda 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(t1.question_id, t1.id) AS ID
    FROM qanda t1   
    WHERE :id IN(t1.question_id=:id, t1.id)
    ) B ON qanda.id = B.ID;
```

Comment: Why would you use `COALESCE` and not `OR`?